# Technisches Deutsch: translation for "current-gain bandwidth product"

Tags: english-to-german, technical-terminology

I don’t understand how I can translate “current-gain bandwidth product”

I have found the following translation:

1. gain bandwidth product  - Verstärkungsbandbreitenprodukt
2. current-gain bandwidth – Stromverstärkungsbandbreite

I am looking for the translation for “current-gain bandwidth product”

Can I translate it as  Stromverstärkungsbandbreitenprodukt?

Comment: German Wikipedia has section on Verstärkungs-Bandbreite-Produkt in it's article on  op amps ([link](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operationsverst%C3%A4rker#Frequenzkompensation_und_Verst%C3%A4rkungs-Bandbreite-Produkt)) I strongly suspect  though that you'd need a background in electrical engineering to knowledgeably answer this.

Comment: If its GBW (gain bandwidth product) that your text is talking about, then your translation might be correct - But that's hard to see without more context. When targetting electrical engineers, you'd probably not even translate the term but use the abbreviation.

Comment: You should show more context. Similar to the Wikipedia article, some people might prefer to write it as Stromverstärkungs-Bandbreite-Produkt. Or you could also write "Produkt aus Stromverstärkung und Bandbreite". Which version to choose may depend on the context. Are you using this in continuous text or in a table or diagram?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about transistors, Transitfrequenz is the correct term. If you are talking about op amps, they are voltage amplifiers, not current amplifiers, so you use Verstärkungs-Bandbreite-Produkt. As noted elsewhere, the English abbreviation GBP is common.
[Bandbreite-Angaben bei schnellen
Operationsverstärkern](https://www.beam-verlag.de/app/download/30158361/HF-Praxis+3-2018+V.pdf)